# Linebreak in a sqlite query

Tags: python, sqlite, line-breaks

I'm using the below to return the results from a sqlite query in python.

```
data = str(des.fetchmany()) +','+ str(date.fetchone())
```

but i'm getting a string with line-breakers and [] or () that i'd like to remove.

```
[(u"text", u'text', number)],(u'yyyy-mm-dd',)
```

how can i achieve a cleaner string without those line-breakers,[] and ()?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That actually isn't a string, it looks like a weird type of list. The [] and () are indicative of a list and a tuple respectively. To make it cleaner, get each string individually, and use `stringvariable.decode("UTF-8)` to get rid of that ugly u preceding all of your elements.

Comment: almost everything worked fine. but for the date yyyy-mm-dd i'm still getting this (u'2013-12-31',) even using the decode in the following code:    str(date.fetchone()).decode("utf-8")  . any thoughts?

Comment: That is a tuple, so do `variable[0]` when referencing that string